# Is There a Way to Search by the Opposite of a Category in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system

I am wondering if there is a way a magento developer would be able to create or find something that would search by the opposite of a category.

For example, given 100 total products and a category x which holds 70 products, is there a way to know what the remaining thirty products are?  Besides, of course, crossing off category x's products one by one on a list of the total number of products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to query the DB. Filtering on the `category_id` that you want. I don't think there will be a better way.

See: `catalog_category_product` and **note** that there are columns: `category_id` and `product_id`.

You should be able to use the `category_product` resourceModel to set this up. Set the filter to be `!=` to the `category_id` you don't want.

If you have trouble with the actual code, open a new question.